# flowchart pattern

Tags: flowchart

I got this from one test and really didn't get the point.

[image]

Which one of the following choices might describe the flow chart above in natu
ral language patterns?

1. If..then..and if..then..
2. If..or..then..
3. If..then..else..
4. If..and..then..
5. If..then..again

Which one of the following choices correctly identifies the flowchart above?

1. Selection pattern
2. Branch pattern
3. Infinite loop pattern
4. Sequence pattern
5. Terminating loop pattern

Note: It is not from my homework; I am serious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question's answers seem like all poor choices, but I'd have to guess 3 by elimination.  There is no concept of AND or OR in the chart, ruling out 1, 2, and 4.  It might be 5 if it said "If then ELSE again", but it doesn't.

5 for the second one because it is a loop and there is a termination case.  Branching (Condition) and Sequence (B, A) patterns are represented as well, but the biggest one is the terminating loop.

Perhaps it requires more context from
class discussion or sonething.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! it makes much sense for me. Any text book covering this stuff in details?

Comment: There are also something called branch pattern and selection pattern. What is the difference between them? I saw them in an online test choices.

Comment: Not sure.  Selection may refer to being able to choose multiple options, whereas branching only allows one option?

Comment: Probably. I also guess selection refers switch-case, while branching refers to if-else.